# Как настроить Graylog через docker-compose?

Tags: docker, администрирование, docker-compose, devops, graylog

Пытаюсь поднять Graylog при помощи docker-compose  на Windows 10 (Docker Desctop / Docker Engine v.20.10.8) и вроде бы всё настроил, но из всей сервисной инфраструктуры, которая состоит из MongoDB, Mongo-Express, ElasticSearch и GrayLog - сам сервис GrayLog при запуске валится по **Exit(1)**.

При этом файлы конфигурации *graylog.conf* и *log4j2.xml* залинкованы через *volumes ./services/configs/graylog:/usr/share/graylog/data/config*.

```
version: "3.9"

services:
    mongodb:
        image: mongo:5.0.2
        restart: always
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: mdbpwd
        volumes:
            - ./services/mongodb/data:/data/db
        networks:
            - myapp

    mongodb-express:
        image: mongo-express:0.54.0
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8081:8081
        environment:
            ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongodb
            ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN: 'true'
            ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_DATABASE: admin
            ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
            ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: mepwd
        depends_on:
            - mongodb
        networks:
            - myapp

    elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:7.14.0
        environment:
            - http.host=0.0.0.0
            - transport.host=localhost
            - network.host=0.0.0.0
            - xpack.security.enabled=false
            - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
        ulimits:
            memlock:
                soft: -1
                hard: -1
        volumes:
            - ./services/elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        ports:
            - 9200:9200
        networks:
            - myapp

    graylog:
        image: graylog/graylog:4.1.3-2
        environment:
            - GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET=7hcbzmejqecxtzi6
            - GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2=575d18f3224359a3d4e10d5fd8d92d1433a2f8090f81ea4ff2157fcb
            - GRAYLOG_WEB_ENDPOINT_URI=http://127.0.0.1:9000/api
        entrypoint: /usr/bin/tini -- wait-for-it elasticsearch:9200 --  /docker-entrypoint.sh
        volumes: 
            - ./services/graylog/data:/usr/share/graylog/data
            - ./services/configs/graylog:/usr/share/graylog/data/config
        ports: 
            - 9000:9000
            - 514:514
            - 514:514/udp
            - 12201:12201
            - 12201:12201/udp
        depends_on:
            - mongodb
            - elasticsearch
        networks:
            - myapp

networks:
    myapp:
        driver: bridge
```

Сервис GrayLog видимо валится из-за **Operation not permitted** и **Warning can not change owner to graylog:graylog**. Как это можно пофиксить?

```
wait-for-it: waiting 15 seconds for elasticsearch:9200
wait-for-it: elasticsearch:9200 is available after 11 seconds
chown: changing ownership of '/usr/share/graylog/data/config/graylog.conf': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/usr/share/graylog/data/config/log4j2.xml': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/usr/share/graylog/data/config': Operation not permitted
Warning can not change owner to graylog:graylog
2021-08-29 14:04:11,951 ERROR: org.graylog2.bootstrap.CmdLineTool - Invalid configuration
com.github.joschi.jadconfig.ValidationException: The minimum length for "password_secret" is 16 characters.
at org.graylog2.Configuration.validatePasswordSecret(Configuration.java:340) ~[graylog.jar:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_302]
at com.github.joschi.jadconfig.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotation(ReflectionUtils.java:53) ~[graylog.jar:?]
at com.github.joschi.jadconfig.JadConfig.invokeValidatorMethods(JadConfig.java:221) ~[graylog.jar:?]
at com.github.joschi.jadconfig.JadConfig.process(JadConfig.java:100) ~[graylog.jar:?]
at org.graylog2.bootstrap.CmdLineTool.processConfiguration(CmdLineTool.java:420) [graylog.jar:?]
at org.graylog2.bootstrap.CmdLineTool.run(CmdLineTool.java:236) [graylog.jar:?]
at org.graylog2.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:45) [graylog.jar:?]
```

Comment: `chown: changing ownership` - ошибка так как `user: graylog`. Удалите это (внутри контейнер будет работать от root), либо заранее выставите владельца `graylog` в Dockerfile, но предварительно его надо создать и желательно сделать groupadd, useradd - как в примере [создается пользователь laradock](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/master/workspace/Dockerfile#L50). А `PGID` и `PUID` выставляется, чтобы ваши замонтированные каталоги в вашей системе (не внутри контейнера) имели определенного пользователя, который указан через эти IDшники.

Comment: @totalpusher параметр `user: graylog` не имеет никакого влияния (видимо это что-то очень древнее и уже не используется). Я убрал его. Но суть остается та же. А пример, который ты  подсказал (спасибо за него) - это Dockerfile. А я оперирую с docker-compose и при этом в доке по GrayLog https://docs.graylog.org/en/4.0/pages/installation/docker.html нет упоминаний про пользователя (см. Example Version 3). Но есть ниже по документации _Graylog is running as USER graylog with the ID 1100 in Docker. That ID need to be able to read the configuration files you place into the container_.

Comment: Тогда нужно создать пользователя graylog и прибить ему 1100 в Dockerfile. Используется docker-compose? Это не меняет ничего, это всего лишь обертка на докером. Можно сделать Dockerfile, в котором `FROM graylog/graylog:4.1.3-2` и его подставить в docker-compose через `build: context: . dockerfile: ./docker/my-graylog/Dockerfile`.

Comment: Но тут проблема вообще в другом. Запустите образ без всяких монтирований и войдите в контейнер. Там будет каталог `/usr/share/graylog/` от пользователя graylog. Когда docker-compose монтирует каталог, он монтируется от рута (ID=1), и соответственно в докере он также виден как созданный от root. Graylog это видит и хочет принудительно поменять пользователя, но это ему не удается, не хватает привилегий. Надо как-то правильно замонтировать, но пока не придумал.